# BIGNUM error when comiling asdcplib

Tags: software-installation, compiling

Just to begin with:

I'm a big Linux/Ubuntu newbie.

Now my problem: I am trying to compile/install asdcplib.

```
jannik@jannik-notebook:~/Downloads/asdcplib-2.7.19$ sudo ./configure
[sudo] Passwort für jannik: 
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for ranlib... (cached) ranlib
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking for OpenSSL headers in /usr/local/ssl/include... found
checking for OpenSSL libraries... not found
checking for OpenSSL... no
checking for Expat XML Parser... no
checking for Xerces C++ Parser... no
checking for --with-python... no
checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... yes
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating win32/Makefile
config.status: creating win32/Makefile.mak
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
jannik@jannik-notebook:~/Downloads/asdcplib-2.7.19$ sudo make
Making all in src
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/home/jannik/Downloads/asdcplib-2.7.19/src“ wird betreten
make  all-am
make[2]: Verzeichnis „/home/jannik/Downloads/asdcplib-2.7.19/src“ wird betreten
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"asdcplib\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"asdcplib\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"2.7.19\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"asdcplib\ 2.7.19\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"asdcplib@cinecert.com\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"asdcplib\" -DVERSION=\"2.7.19\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAVE_LIBPTHREAD=1 -I.    -g   -g -O2 -MT KM_prng.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/KM_prng.Tpo -c -o KM_prng.lo KM_prng.cpp
libtool: compile:  g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"asdcplib\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"asdcplib\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"2.7.19\" "-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"asdcplib 2.7.19\"" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"asdcplib@cinecert.com\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"asdcplib\" -DVERSION=\"2.7.19\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAVE_LIBPTHREAD=1 -I. -g -g -O2 -MT KM_prng.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/KM_prng.Tpo -c KM_prng.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/KM_prng.o
KM_prng.cpp: In function 'void Kumu::Gen_FIPS_186_Value(const byte_t*, ui32_t, byte_t*, ui32_t)':
KM_prng.cpp:219:10: error: aggregate 'BIGNUM c_2powb' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
   BIGNUM c_2powb, c_2, c_b;
          ^~~~~~~
KM_prng.cpp:219:19: error: aggregate 'BIGNUM c_2' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
   BIGNUM c_2powb, c_2, c_b;
                   ^~~
KM_prng.cpp:219:24: error: aggregate 'BIGNUM c_b' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
   BIGNUM c_2powb, c_2, c_b;
                        ^~~
KM_prng.cpp:220:3: error: 'BN_init' was not declared in this scope
   BN_init(&c_2powb);  BN_init(&c_2);  BN_init(&c_b);
   ^~~~~~~
KM_prng.cpp:220:3: note: suggested alternative: 'BN_print'
   BN_init(&c_2powb);  BN_init(&c_2);  BN_init(&c_b);
   ^~~~~~~
   BN_print
KM_prng.cpp:248:14: error: aggregate 'BIGNUM bn_tmp' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
       BIGNUM bn_tmp, bn_xkey, bn_x_n;
              ^~~~~~
KM_prng.cpp:248:22: error: aggregate 'BIGNUM bn_xkey' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
       BIGNUM bn_tmp, bn_xkey, bn_x_n;
                      ^~~~~~~
KM_prng.cpp:248:31: error: aggregate 'BIGNUM bn_x_n' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
       BIGNUM bn_tmp, bn_xkey, bn_x_n;
                               ^~~~~~
Makefile:1139: recipe for target 'KM_prng.lo' failed
make[2]: *** [KM_prng.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Verzeichnis „/home/jannik/Downloads/asdcplib-2.7.19/src“ wird verlassen
Makefile:747: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/home/jannik/Downloads/asdcplib-2.7.19/src“ wird verlassen
Makefile:361: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I don't know how to fix this and to make it work. 
I tried to downgrade openssl to 1.0.2 but that didnt work.